# Wikidata get Industry of Person

Tags: wikidata

Wikidata provides Person’s occupation information.

I there a way to get Industry of that occupation? Like Actor, Choreographer, Director belongs to **Entertainment** industry.

Is that information available on wikidata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but this here works better than I expected: https://w.wiki/YP2

```
SELECT ?industry ?industryLabel ?profession ?professionLabel  WHERE {
  {
    
      ?item wdt:P425 ?value.
      ?i wdt:P279 ?item.
    }
    GROUP BY ?value
    ORDER BY DESC (?ct)
    LIMIT 1000
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?ct) (?value)
```

Even the simplistic

```
SELECT ?professionLabel ?industryLabel WHERE {
   ?profession wdt:P425 ?industry.
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

seems to work okay(ish), but the added layer of indirection and sorting by count make it slightly more focussed on actual jobs, and not `warrior` -> works at -> `war`.